# Why is modal semantic ui not working?

Tags: php, yii, semantic-markup

I'm a beginner using the Yii web framwork , and I'd like know why this code is not working.

In main.php

```
<a href="#" onclick="modal()"> test modal</a>
```

In script.js

```
function modal(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=Site/ModalRegister',
        success: function(){
            $('.large.modal').modal('show');
        }

    });         
}
```

In siteController.php

```
public function actionModalRegister(){
    $this->renderPartial('//site/ModalRegister');
}
```

In site/ModalRegister.php

```
<div class="ui large modal">ddd</div>
```

Comment: i click link <a href="#" onclick="modal()"> test modal</a>, but modal isn't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you do this

```
function modal(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=Site/ModalRegister',
        success: function(){
            $('.large.modal').modal('show');
        }

    });         
}
```

On success you try to show the `<div class="ui large modal">ddd</div>` that comes from the ajax itself. But before you show it you have to insert it someplace in the DOM of the page. You should change it to something like

```
function modal(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=Site/ModalRegister',
        success: function(html){ 
            $( "body" ).append(html); 
            $('.large.modal').modal('show');
        }
    });         
}
```

Comment: sorry i have a problem again,

This code is normally work. When i click first time to show modal it normally work, but when i click second time to show this modal it work, but i can't close this modal. 
Error massage is : 

> Transition: That animation is already occurring, cancelling repeated
> animation.

 How to set or what error ?

Comment: `$('.ui.large.modal').remove();$( "body" ).append(html); 
            $('.large.modal').modal('show');`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the code that defines function `modal()` isn't loaded when you re-render your page using ajax.

Check whether you get a javascript error in your browser when you click on the link but the modal doesn't show. You probably do.

You will need to add the function definition code in your **partial view too** so that when you render your view partially using ajax, function `modal()` is defined.